# How to draw shape like this one in android?

Tags: android, shapes

I am trying to draw shape like this picture below in android. I want to place this view on a RelativeLayout. And I will set `onClickListener` for this View. Is it possible to draw a `View` like this and set `onClickListener`?

[image]

Could anyone guide me how to draw a shape like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targetting api level 11 and up, there is a method already included for rotating views

in the xml, call `android:rotation="45"`, or if wanted programmatically, get a reference to the view and call `someView.setRotation(45)`

```
final LinearLayout textContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayoutId);
textContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        textContainer.setRotation(getRotation() + 45);
    }
});
```

Really though, this works [image: try it out]

Comment: Rotating view works but the problem is when I tried to set onClickListener then it wont work.

Comment: setRotation() works via View properties introduced in 3.0 so it should work.

Comment: I want to show the rotated view before click event. And if user click this rotated view then something will happen.

Comment: Okay. easy.  Set it's intial rotation in the XML layout file, and set an OnClickListener for the layout containing the textview as shown in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom `View`, override `onDraw` method. There you rotate the `Canvas` and draw rectangle and text.

You also need to override `onMeasure` to get proper size for the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the view by some degree. That should solve your problem, shouldn't it?

Comment: I tried it. It's can rotate the view but the problem is when I tried to set click event then it wont work. Could you please explain it little bit more?